# Rails 4: Exsiting Column Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have added an existing column to my table as an integer.

In my views I have:

```
<%= f.label :php_rate, 'PHP Rate" %>
<%= f.number_field :php_rate %>
```

My schema show:

```
t.integer  "php_rate"
```

If I add a number, from views, the number wont save in the database. Is there an issue with my rails app?

Comment: You forgot to _white listing_ the new field in the controller.. I'm sure.. :)

Comment: FLIPPING HELL!! Yes! I have! OMG! Thanks!!!!

Comment: LOL.. ROFL.. I do the same every time..